# Looking for a PHP script that can clean up bad HTML

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am in the process of writing a PHP command line script to convert hundreds of HTML snippets into Markdown using the [Markdownify](http://milianw.de/projects/markdownify/) library. However, I have come across a situation where some of my HTML is not structured well enough to be used with Markdownify. So I first need to send my HTML through some library that can clean it up and add optional closing tags, etc. I will be working with partial blocks of HTML, not complete HTML documents, so the HTML that is returned must be partial (and not include the doctype, etc).

Do you know of a PHP script that can convert HTML to XHTML?

### Solution:

Utilize the [PHP DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php). It will format your HTML even if it is broken. Then you can extract the cleaned up HTML:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //use this to prevent warning messages from displaying because of the bad HTML

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($badHtml);
$goodHtml = $doc->saveHTML();
```

This will return a full HTML document (with the cleaned up version in the body tag), even though I passed it a partial block of HTML, so I can extract the cleaned up partial with this regex:

```
$goodHtmlPartial = trim(ereg_replace('(.*)<body>(.*)</body>(.*)', '\2', $goodHtml));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could load the HTML into [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) then [save](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) it as XML.

Comment: If the HTML is very broken, then the DOM parser won't like it either.

Comment: @ElYobo True, but it'd be worth a try before moving on to heavier options like HTML Purifier.

Comment: You're right, it is probably worth a try, so +1 for the suggestion. The OP said that some of it was insufficiently well structured for the markdownify code to handle it though, and I've found DOM to be very fussy in the past, so I wouldn't hold out much hope :)

Answer (score 8):

Any reason not to use tidy ?

http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

It can clean up your html and give you only the body section.

```
$tidy = tidy_repair_string($content,array(
                           'indent'         => true,
                           'output-html'   => true,
                           'wrap'           => 80,
                           'show-body-only' => true,
                           'clean' => true,
                           'input-encoding' => 'utf8',
                           'output-encoding' => 'utf8',
                           'logical-emphasis' => false,
                           'bare' => true,
                                          ));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org); it's fantastic at cleaning up poor HTML and can act as a filter for potentially malicious code as well.

Comment: +1 for HTML Purifier. Good library. Confusing documentation though.

Comment: As Phil notes, it's probably worth trying the DOM approach first.  HTML Purifier isn't really that hard; it depends how much of the config you need to mess with.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you using the [DOMDocument->loadHTML()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) method. It will format your HTML even if it is broken. Later, you can save it as XML to obtain XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not PHP, but the BeautifulSoup library for python has parsers that are good for making valid html for just about any old crap.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

                    $dom = new \DOMDocument;
                    $dom->loadHTML($bad_html);

                    // Strip wrapping <html> and <body> tags
                    $mock = new \DOMDocument;
                    $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
                    foreach ($body->childNodes as $child) {
                        $mock->appendChild($mock->importNode($child, true));
                    }

                    $fixed = trim($mock->saveHTML());
                    echo $fixed;
```